# PWA Issues or confusion - offline.html & service worker

Tags: progressive-web-apps

My site works nicely as a PWA and I am trying to improve it. I have a couple of things going on and I am not sure if this is normal behavior or not.

Starting with offline.html. Right now I have a standard simple piece of text that say you are viewing example in offline mode. There is no header/footer or any other content. I'd really like to improve that but where and how much can I improve it? It doesn't seem to act like a normal page. I also find a problem on my child pages where when testing and looking at a waterfall chart, offline.html is coming back as a 404. I doubt this is normal.

Secondly, when I run a lighthouse test on a child page like example.com/childpage I get the following;

1. Current page does not respond with a 200 when offline
2. start_url does not respond with a 200 when offlineThe start_url did respond, but not via a service worker.
3. Does not register a service worker that controls page and start_url

I've tried to search for answers but I'm not having much luck. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I only understand from a VueJs perspective.

1. If your app isn't registering your service worker, then the service worker won't be able to intercept the http request, please see attached pic. basically you need to get that registered before you continue.
   [image: List item]

   reference: https://www.sicara.ai/blog/2017-06-30-part-three-progressive-web-app-with-vue-js-webpack-material-design
2. you can add a `<noscript>` tag into your index.html which will catch when your JS doesn't load see: https://web.dev/without-javascript/
3. Going back to registering your service worker; You need to make sure your webpack, or like in my case my vue.config.js is actually registering your PWA correctly, including the service-worker.js

```
pwa: {
    themeColor: '#2F1B55',
    msTileColor: '#000000',
    iconPaths: {
      favicon32: 'static/favicon-32x32.png',
    },
    workboxPluginMode: 'InjectManifest',
    workboxOptions: {
      swSrc: 'service-worker.js',
    },
    navigateFallback: 'yourDir/public/index.html'
  }
```

`navigateFallback` this is important to tell the browser where to start the JS from again when it falls over mid app.

Getting a service worker registered on build is your primary concern. Try reading the article from 1. to get a greater understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your input, I'll read tonight. That said,I can put my mobile device into airplane mode and my entire PWA acts just the way it did when I was online (unless its a DB lookup). This is why I'm a bit confused. Every page that I visited online is available offline. I only get these warnings from lighthouse. In devtools, there is no warning. Cheers.